# Using flexbox, struggling to get justify-content to align objects in center

Tags: html, css, flexbox, containers, justify

How can I get my `<ul class="social">` container to align the `<li class="social">` children into a line in the center of my `<footer>` container? I am trying to use flexbox instead of position absolute so that my icons do not end up overlapping the secondary nav bar inside the footer, which happened previously.  I have fully restructured my footer since then, but am not very proficient in flexbox yet. I have tried using `justification-content: center;` on the `<ul class="social">` container, which did nothing for some reason.  Any help would be appreciated!

Codepen: https://codepen.io/daniel-albano/pen/poJydQj?editors=1100

FOOTER CONTAINER, ALL HTML:

```
<footer>
  <ul class="social">
    <li class="social"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Aki-Weininger-104277784411418/" id="profile-link"
        target="https://www.facebook.com/Aki-Weininger-104277784411418/"> <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"> </i> </a>
    </li>
    <li class="social"> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/akiweininger/?hl=en" id="instagram-link"
        target="https://www.instagram.com/akiweininger/?hl=en"> <i class="fab fa-instagram"> </i> </a> </li>
    <li class="social"> <a href="https://www.behance.net/akiweininger" id="Behance-link" target="https://www.behance.net/akiweininger">
        <i class="fab fa-behance"></i> </a> </li>
    <li class="social"> <a href="https://www.upwork.com/freelancers/~01d4ae188cd67db90c" id="Upwork-link"
        target="https://www.upwork.com/freelancers/~01d4ae188cd67db90c">
        <img class="upwork" src="https://i.imgur.com/Z02P8YO.png" alt="upwork">
      </a> </li>
  </ul> 
  <ul class="navi"> 
      <div class="navi-title">
  Navigation
  </div> 
    <li class="navi">
        <a href="PLACEHOLDER">
          Home
        </a>
      </li>
     <li class="navi">
        <a href="PLACEHOLDER">
          Works
        </a>
      </li>
     <li class="navi">
        <a href="PLACEHOLDER">
          Contact
        </a>
      </li>
  </ul> 
</footer>
```

FOOTER CONTAINER, ALL CSS:

```
footer {
  background-color: #2a7de1;
  padding: 2% 0% 2% 0%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
}
ul.social {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
footer ul.social li.social {
  list-style: none;
}
footer > ul.social li.social a {
  font-size: 2vw;
  margin: 0% 0% 0% 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;

}
footer > ul.social li.social a .fab {
  color: white;
}
footer > ul.social li.social a:hover .fab {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.upwork {
  width: 2.2%;
}
.upwork:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
footer > ul.navi li.navi {
  list-style: none;
}
.navi-title {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'karla';
  font-size: 1.4vw;
    margin: 0% 0% 10% 0%; 
  font-weight: 700;
}
footer > ul.navi li.navi a {
   text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
    font-family: 'karla';
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column-wrap;
}
footer > ul.navi li.navi a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: you can add '  flex-direction:column;' to your social class

Comment: what about your class="navi" how do you want them to be ?

Comment: I'd like to keep the social classes children in a row if possible.

Comment: Navi I want to be slightly more to the left, but I'm trying to get social into the middle first

Answer (score 1):

```
ul.social    
}
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

I think this should solve your problem, but I guess since the last child `li` is having an **image** inside the `li` you might have to adjust the CSS to make the last `li` at the center.

Hope that helps.